# eclipse Orion ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: eclipse-orion

There's an editor `eclipse Orion` that allows for editing source codes in various languages in a web browser. An [instruction](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Orion/How_Tos/Editor_Build#Using_the_standalone_build) says the editor can be set up through these few lines of `HTML` code.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://eclipse.org/orion/editor/releases/4.0/built-editor.css"/>
<script src="http://eclipse.org/orion/editor/releases/4.0/built-editor.min.js"></script>
<script>
/*global require*/
require(["orion/editor/edit"], function(edit) {
    edit({className: "editor"});
});
</script>
```

I pasted these lines into an editor, adapted the paths of the included `.css` and `.js` files and called the page in a web browser. It results in the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`.

There's an alternative instruction that says to include the `-amd` version of the `eclipse Orion` JS files and to also include a certain `require.js` JS file.
Am I missing something or is the instruction missing the hint to always include `require.js` to provide the `require` function?

The instruction is a few years old. I'm using recent Orion build 14.3. Has something changed over the years? Has the require function been provided once in an earlier build?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, requirejs needs to be included, for example with

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.5/require.js></script>
```

If you installed requirejs with bower you might want to use something like

```
<script src="./bower_components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
```

Also see the sourcode of following working Orion example:

http://libingw.github.io/OrionCodeEdit/